# WPF Trigger binding to MVVM property

Tags: wpf, binding, triggers

I have a datatemplate containing an image that I want to be hidden if the the value of a property in a ViewModel is true. Can anyone tell me why the the xaml below does not work?

```
<Image x:Name="img" Source="..\Images\List_16.png" Margin="0,0,5,0">
  <Image.Style>
    <Style>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentListHasPendingChanges}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Image.Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CurrentListHasPendingChanges}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Image.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isn't that

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
```

?

I assume you use INotifyProptyChanged.

**EDIT** I did some Googling and I think you need to use some sort of template in order to make the trigger work.

eg.: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ae2dbfb7-5dd6-4352-bfa1-53634289329d

http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Help_Why_cant_I_use_DataTriggers_with_controls_in_WPF.aspx

Comment: Yes I do implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
When I change the setter as per above, I get the following compile error:

Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Visibility'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property

Comment: Thanks for these, I'll go through them shortly

Answer (score 6):

Try removing "Image" part from Property="Image.Visibility" so you'll have:

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
```

and add TargetType to your Style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
```

Answer (score 6):

I just did something similar using a ContentControl.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentListHasPendingChanges}">
  <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Image x:Name="img" Source="..\Images\List_16.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" Visibility="Hidden" />
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Image.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

From http://karlhulme.wordpress.com/2007/03/06/using-a-contentcontrol-and-datatemplate-to-indicate-new-andor-modified-data/

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion we not need to use Triggers, with only the Binding it works well.
To make binding to a property model, you can use BooleanToVisibilityConverter
Is declared as follows:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And how to use it is simple, just point to the key stated above:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="16"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16" 
       Visibility="{Binding HasError, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
       Source="/myPath;component/Resources/Images/image1.png"/>
```

The property in the ViewModel:

```
private bool _hasError = false;
    public bool HasError
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_messageError); }
        set 
        {
            _hasError = value;                
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.HasError);
        }
    }
```