# WPF DataTrigger won't set Height property of RowDefinition

Tags: .net, wpf, datatrigger, expander

In my application I have a View with this snippet:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Name="DownloadsExpanderRow">
            <RowDefinition.Style>
                <Style TargetType="RowDefinition">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DownloadExpander, Path=IsExpanded}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </RowDefinition.Style>
        </RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Expander Grid.Row="2" Name="DownloadExpander"/>
</Grid>
```

The purpose of all this is to have a main area (Grid row #0) that sizes to fill all space in the grid not taken up by the other rows and an Expander at the bottom that when expanded can be resized to be taller or shorter.

I found that when collapsing the Expander once the GridSplitter had already been used to resize the Expander row that the Expander's contents would appear to disappear but it wouldn't resize the row to take up less space. I found out that this is because the GridSplitter sets the Height value of the row from Auto to something else once it is used to resize.

The obvious workaround from there seemed to be to use a DataTrigger to reset the row height to Auto when the Expander collapses. I chose a DataTrigger with a Setter so that when the Expander is expanded again then its last Height value would be restored (This is my understanding of how setters work).

In practice the DataTrigger is triggering but for some reason the setter doesn't seem to be setting the Height property like I want it to. I tried using the EnterAction and a storyboard to set the height value to auto within the same DataTrigger and it worked. The downside though was that I had no way to restore the height value to what the splitter had it at before it was collapsed and this causes strange behavior with the GridSplitter. Either way the fact that the storyboard worked tells me that the DataTrigger is actually triggering its just that the Setter is not working.

Why isn't my Setter working if it is in fact being triggered?

Comment: Default and trigger both set height to Auto. Is that correct?

Comment: Default is so that it starts out with Auto and I put it in a setter to avoid this issue as explained in this Answer and its comments: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19319456/1504964