# Datatrigger doesn't work?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatrigger

I have a problem. I'd like to hide TabControl where there's no active tab. Information about tabs is kept in WidocznoscTabControl property (if there's any tab WidocznoscTabControl =1, if there's no tab WidocznoscTabControl=0). I've tried to use DataTrigger, but it didn't work and I don't know why. I'm a beginner and I'm still learning. That's why I ask you for help. This is a part of MainWindowResources.xaml file

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspacesTemplate">
    <TabControl 
      x:Name="Tabs"
      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ClosableTabItemTemplate}"
      Margin="4"
        />

     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=WidocznoscTabControl}" Value="0">
             <Setter TargetName="Tabs" Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
          </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

WidocznoscTabControl is declarated and initialized in MainWindowViewModel.cs file.

Comment: need more information: what is type of WidocznoscTabControl ?

Comment: Type of WidocznoscTabControl is int. However, I've tried to use bool instead of int and it didn't work too.

Comment: Are you setting DataContext Okay? Do you see any binding errors in the output window when you run the application in debug mode?

Comment: Well, DataContext is set properly. What is more, there's no error in output window.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you do not notify your View of the changes in the ViewModel. Make sure that OnPropertyChanged called if WidocznoscTabControl is set to zero.

Another cause might be that setting the opacity to zero does not have the desired effect. You should try setting the property Visiblity to false instead. Information about how to do that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795476/wpf-trigger-binding-to-mvvm-property).

Comment: Well, I've tried to set Opacity manually to 0 and it did have the desired effect. Of course value of WidocznoscTabControl is set to 0. (If I click on one button WidocznoscTabControl is set to 1, if I click on another one WidocznoscTabControl is set to 0. In order to be sure about value of this property, after every click MessageBox with value of WidocznoscTabControl is shown). But if you can, look at this property:

Comment: public int WidocznoscTabControl
{
            get
            {
                return _WidocznoscTabControl;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != _WidocznoscTabControl) _WidocznoscTabControl = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => WidocznoscTabControl);
            }
        }

Comment: Okay, then i really dont have definitive answer. Sorry.